# gradlew genSource 'Mods\NewMod\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: gradle

I am trying to generate a Fabric loader Minecraft mod. To do this we have to use Gradle with the command `gradlew genSource` in terminal. When I do this I get the error

I am in the main directory of  the mod folder
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVO9P.png)

```
gradlew genSource
'Mods\NewMod\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
I am using the jre1.8.0_271 and AdoptOpenJDK's jdk-8.0.275.1-hotspot

Answer (score 0):

"gradlew genSource" is outdated (I don't know why)

do ./gradlew genSource

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).